# How to cache filters?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, caching, memcached, invalidation

I am about to implement sort and filter functionality for my site.

I am planning to use memcache for caching results for individual pages(each filter applied is a different page).

Issue is what should be the memcache key for each page. I was planning to append each filter permutation in memcache key like

some_id_color_red_size_l_page_1 and so on.

But Issue is with invalidating these many cache keys as these keys grows exponentially. and If some product is updated some where, I have to update keys for all the pages where it appears.

Any idea how to implement this in more optimized way? Or any other mechanism other than memcache to achieve this?

Comment: How often do those values actually change and how much different filters (not exactly but in relation to the items in the database) are we talking about here?

Comment: The values color, size do change at some time, around once in our i think. and filters would be around 6-7.